# Make one instance of multiple uWSGI workers perform a extra function

Tags: uwsgi

I have a python flask app running on uWSGI with a config file that specifics it to spawn multiple workers (which I am assuming are identical processes).

Everything works well except for one part: the python app runs a bash command to download an update a database every day using a scheduler, which needs to run only once but multiple processes means that it runs multiple times at the same time, thus corrupting the downloaded file.

Is there a way to run this bash command on only one instance of uWSGI workers? I can't run the bash command as a separate cron job (the database update has to integrate seamlessly with the app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [The uWSGI cron-like interface](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Cron.html#the-uwsgi-cron-like-interface)

> uWSGI’s master has an internal **cron-like** facility that can generate
>   events at predefined times. You can use it

You can set the options for example to:

```
[uwsgi]
; every two hours
cron = 0 -2 -1 -1 -1 /usr/bin/backup_my_home --recursive
```

Is that sufficient?

Comment: Thanks, that actually helps a lot!